# Application Insights .net core : Process was called on the TelemetrySink after it was disposed, the telemetry data was dropped

Tags: azure-application-insights

We have noticed several situations where telemetry has not showed up in AI. After some digging I found entries like this in the log from FileDiagnosticsTelemetryModule.

Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TraceSource Error: 43 : Process was called on the TelemetrySink after it was disposed, the telemetry data was dropped.

Sometimes telemetry arrives, sometimes not. There is only one other post I found on this but
the article did not address much. Has anyone seen this before? Anything I should be looking at?

Startup.cs

ConfigureXXXServices

```
   ` services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer>(new RoleNameInitializer(ApplicationName));  
    services.AddSingleton(new OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer());
    services.AddSingleton(new HttpDependenciesParsingTelemetryInitializer());

    var aiOptions = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
    {
        EnableAdaptiveSampling                    = false,
        DeveloperMode                             = false,
        EnableDebugLogger                         = true,
        EnableQuickPulseMetricStream              = true,
        ApplicationVersion                        = "2.0.0",
        EnableDependencyTrackingTelemetryModule   = true,
        EnableRequestTrackingTelemetryModule      = true,
        AddAutoCollectedMetricExtractor           = true,
        EnableAppServicesHeartbeatTelemetryModule = true,
        EnableEventCounterCollectionModule        = true,
        //EnablePerformanceCounterCollectionModule = true,                
        InstrumentationKey                         = Configuration.GetSection("Logging")["LoggingServiceApiKey"],                   
    };

    services.AddSingleton(typeof(ITelemetryChannel), new ServerTelemetryChannel() { StorageFolder = @"c:\TelemetryService_ReportingAgent" });
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(aiOptions);
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<CustomTraceOnlyProcessor>();
    services.AddScoped<LogContext>();
    services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, LogContextInitializer>();          

    //if (Environment == "Local")
    //{
    Console.WriteLine("Setting up Telemetry Channel Diagnostics Tracing. See c:\\logs for details..");
    services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.Tracing.FileDiagnosticsTelemetryModule>();

    services.ConfigureTelemetryModule<Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.Tracing.FileDiagnosticsTelemetryModule>((module, options) =>
    {
        module.LogFilePath = "C:\\logs";
        module.LogFileName = ApplicationName + "_TelemetryChannelLog.txt";
        module.Severity    = "Verbose";
    });
    //}


    services.AddLogging(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddApplicationInsights(Configuration.GetSection("Logging")["LoggingServiceApiKey"]);
        builder.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("", LogLevel.Information);
        builder.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("Microsoft", LogLevel.Error);
    });`
```

ConfigureXXX

```
   `   // Could these be the Telemetry Sinks getting disposed of too soon?

      loggerFactory.AddDebug(LogLevel.Debug);
      loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));   

      appLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnShutdown);

      private void OnShutdown()
      {
       Console.WriteLine("Shutting Down");
       this.TelemetryClient.Flush();   // this.TelemetryClient is a non-DI supplied instance (new) created in ctor..
       Thread.Sleep(9000);             // was 5000. 
      }`
```

Thanks for your time looking over this. Any help is appreciated..
Travis

Comment: Did you found the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I'm still getting this to this day. Trying to figure out how to explain this one. Are you getting the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have DeveloperMode=false which means that "TelemetryChannel respects production sending policies defined by other properties".
Try to set it to "DeveloperMode=true" then "TelemetryChannel sends telemetry to Application Insights immediately during the entire lifetime of the application".

Comment: Where do you set this?